# Server Error in '/' Application this problem not show before,It was well run

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

**This Error Message as the below :**

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /controlPanel/deleteBackup/8595db89-b019-41c2-83bb-ef2b45ffd92d

**and this is Html code**

```
<a href='@Url.Action("deleteBackup", "controlPanel", new { id = item.ID })' class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

**too I try this way**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "deleteBackup", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
```

*Note : deleteBackup Action is in the Same controller for that I not write controller Name in ActionLink*

**codes at the Controller as the below :**

```
public ActionResult deleteBackup(string id)
        {

            if (id!=null)
            {
                db.Backups.Remove(db.Backups.Find(id));
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("BackUpSetting");
        }
```

**and this is RouteConfig Class Codes as :**

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

*Note : this action is Authenticated For the Current User*

**Why was it working before? But why now is this wrong?**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Does it get here `return RedirectToAction("BackUpSetting")` when you breakpoint?

Comment: I placed a break point at the begin of action but not called it

Comment: Why not stop at the break point this means that it does not call action. Why is this happening?

Comment: @AbdulmajeedNajiAlshari Can you share the controller class code with attributes applied at controller level?

Comment: What do you mean and why I did not understand

Comment: If it's not hitting your `deleteBackup` method it sounds like an issue with route configuration see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: I add RouteConfig class codes to question please preview  my question

Comment: @AbdulmajeedNajiAlshari Route config seems fine providing your controller name is correct. You don't have any http attributes on the deleteBackup method do you? Like designating as post/delete request?

Comment: I use this [HttpPost] on the deleteBackup

Comment: Why use like above codes in  other controller is well run like the below comment as :

Comment: <a href='@Url.Action("aboutMember", "Members", new { memberId = Model.TrainerMembers[i].memberId })'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My problem Solved** after so many and many attempts . 
**only Remove [HttpPost] from the top of the deleteBackup Action**

Comment: Note / I have mentioned in my comment that I used the [HttpPost] property on the deleteBackup Action

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "deleteBackup", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" }, put your controller name here)
```

Comment: how that . My problem occure in other a tags some of a tags not use for only delete operation some of them use to download and other for upload Backups Files